# Remapping tracking columns to base class names with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

This is my current class domain model:

```
public class Customer : TrackedEntity
{
    ... // Working Properties Omitted
}

public abstract class TrackedEntity
{
     public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } // Maps to field 'CreateDate'
     public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; } // Maps to field 'ModDate'
     public string  CreatedBy { get; set; } 
     public string ModifiedBy { get; set; } // Maps to field 'ModBy'
}
```

Each database table I am mapping (from EFv4) contains tracking fields with the same types but different names from those in `TrackedEntity`.  Is there a way to establish a mapping convention so you do not need to manually map these columns for all entities that derive from TrackedEntity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually setup mappings in your map creations to handle mismatched names:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropA))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropB));
```

Keep in mind that you only need to run the map creations once and they are good for the duration of your applicaton.  I put mine in App Start in global.asax so I know they are all in one place and I don't have to fuss with them when I'm actually using AutoMapper.

Comment: Yes this is an option if you want to map these columns in every type.  My question is looking for a way to define a _convention_ for handling this.